# Which ad formats uses tinder?

Tags: android, admob, ads, tinder

I have an app with a cardview, just like tinder.
Now I want to add Ads with AdMob.
AdMob offers 4 Ad formats:

1. Banner
2. Interstitial (Full-page ads)
3. Rewarded (Videos)
4. Native

I'd like to have Ads like Tinder in my app, but I dont know which ad format Tinder uses in their cards. None of these 4 seem to be what tinder uses (native is in closed beta).

Does Tinder have their own thing or are that just really big banner?
How would I go about making the same kind of Ads Tinder uses?

Answer (score 2):

Tinder have their own advertising platform in partnership with both google and Facebook.

What you’re looking for is the native option which would require you to query an API and then display the data.

Keep in mind that you’ll also be responsible for notifying the server of ad clicks.

Comment: 1) "What you’re looking for is the native option which would require you to query an API and then display the data."

2) "Keep in mind that you’ll also be responsible for notifying the server of ad clicks."

Do I only have to do that with the native option? Does that happen automatically for (let's say) banner?

Comment: That would depend greatly on the SDK that you would use. I would assume that the SDK would provide an out of the box View that has all the required tracking and functions built in for the non native options. You could confirm this inside the docs for your chosen ad partner.

Comment: I'll use AdMob.

Comment: And if I define some other area as the standard banner-size, wouldn't the creators of the ads create new ads extra for that format?

Comment: No. For banner ads you can create them in any size, the ad will just fill the view proportionally which may leave white space around the edges if it can not fill perfectly. See the docs here https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner

Comment: But I'm not planning on using banner ads, but native ads. How does the creator know to design an ad for the native area I create?

Comment: You will need to design native ads that fit a specified format and size. The creators will only ever provide fixed size assets that you’ll need to build native experiences around.